# Android JNI crashing on WVGA devices, but not HVGA

Tags: bitmap, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault, android-ndk

I'm doing some bimap manipulation, and my code works well on HVGA 
devices.

However, on WVGA, the JNI crashes with a seg fault.

What could the potential difference be? To be clear I am accessing 
bitmaps through the following pseudocode:

```
ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bmp, &dpixels) 
dpixels[pos] = // some color distortion
```

Due to the sig fault I am guessing that I am accessing a bad memory 
address through dpixels. But I am not clear why there would be a 
difference between WVGA & HVGA devices.

Comment: should we have a more details log messages ?

Comment: should we not talk in the third person ?